# Stereo phone jack: purpose of terminals 1 and 6

Tags: connector, headphones

Here's the datasheet

[image]

While I understand pins/pads 2-5, why it has 1 and 6 instead of having just single terminal? Is it like *ground* and *protective ground*? Where am I expected to connect 1 and 6? One of them is surely signal ground, but another?

Comment: Are you sure that's T-R-S and not T-R-R-S?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a socket for a 4-pole jack as used on mobile phones. On the PJ-W27B2-06D (leftmost version) you have

- Tip: speaker left.  Pin 2.
- Ring 1: speaker right. Pin 3.
- Ring 2: Mic or ground Pin 6.
- Sleeve: ground or Mic. Pin 1.

Pins 4 and 5 allow audio through to internal speaker, for example, if the jack is unplugged.

If you don't need the mic line then connect 6 to 1 to give better sleeve connection.

Comment: Ah, it involves microphone line! Could there be any type of "active" mic (output) which will feel bad if connecting 6 to 1 (shorting mic out to the ground)?

Comment: Many feed a small bias voltage out on the mic contact for electret mics. This is always current limited to prevent any trouble if regular 3-pin earphones are plugged in.

Comment: Not all use sleeve ground